# I'm unable to get the total count of records in a collection - Wix Code

Tags: javascript, velo

I'm trying to get the total number of records in a wix collection using the code show below:

> ```
> wixData.query("Client").count().then((num) => {
>               clientTableIndex = num;
>           }).catch((error) => {
>               let errorMsg = error.message;
>               let code = error.code;
>               console.log("@Public IndexOf().");
>               console.log(code + ": " + errorMsg);
>           });
> ```

But for some reason its not giving me the count, neither it is showing up any error. I also tried using the `find()` like so:

```
wixData.query("Client")
                .find()
                .then((num) => {
                    clientTableIndex = num.totalCount;
                }).catch((error) => {
                    let errorMsg = error.message;
                    let code = error.code;
                    console.log(code + ": " + errorMsg);
                });
            console.log(clientTableIndex);
            let insertToClient = {
                "memberId": wixUsers.currentUser.id,
                "title": "Client0".concat(clientTableIndex + 1)
```

But still no luck. I've given full permission to the Collection `Client` in wix database. See below:

[image]

I'm kind of stuck at this moment. I'm sure, something I'm missing, which causing this issue.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1st method is correct. You are setting the number to a variable which may be the reason you are not "seeing" the number.

Set it to a text value or console log it like below to see the count

```
wixData.query('Client').count().then( (num) => {
    console.log(num);
    $w("#text1").text = "" + num;   
});
```

Comment: Yeah, actually I was trying to use `clientTableIndex` variable outside the `.then()` function, that was the reason why, I was loosing the data. More on this, you can find [here](https://www.wix.com/corvid/forum/community-discussion/i-m-unable-to-get-the-total-count-of-records-in-a-collection-wix-code?origin=member_posts_page)